# Set a unique URL for each user profile

Tags: php, html, url

I'm trying to set unique URL's for each user's profile on my website. So far I have docname.php?u=username, but am trying to get it set up like facebook: facebook.com/username, or medium: medium.com/@username.

Thanks.

Comment: Google "url rewriting"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really a PHP question. You'll need to use a .htaccess file (if you're using an Apache server) or equivalent. You'll need to add a line, something like the following:

`RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ docname.php?u=$1`